# Idiomatic way to restart a go routine

Tags: go

I have two go routine performing two long running task. There are a few conditions were these routines can error out. I am trying to see if there is a way to restart the routines once they error out. I have to also avoid a restart if the routine is cancelled.

I have added the below code now. Please suggest if this is an idiomatic way to do this.

```
func f1(ctx context.Context) error {
    fmt.Println("[f1] start")
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        fmt.Println("[f1] graceful exit")
        return nil
    }
}

func f2(ctx context.Context) error {
    fmt.Println("[f2] start")
    select {
    case <-time.After(1 * time.Second):
        // simulating an error condition
        fmt.Println("[f2] errored exit")
        return fmt.Errorf("error")
    case <-ctx.Done():
        fmt.Println("[f2] graceful exit")
        return nil
    }
}

func manage(ctx context.Context, f func(ctx context.Context) error) {
    for {
        err := f(ctx)
        if err == nil {
            return
        }
        <-time.After(1 * time.Second)
    }
}

func main() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())

    go manage(ctx, f1)
    go manage(ctx, f2)

    // delay to see the exeution
    <-time.After(5 * time.Second)
    cancel()
    <-time.After(5 * time.Second)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no idiomatic way to do this. Go routines don't arbitrarily die and have need of restarting.

Either handle the error inside the go routine and prevent it from ending, or communicate the error back to the point the routine was started, handle it there, and then re-run the go routine on different inputs, if appropriate.

Comment: Here's an example of that https://play.golang.org/p/VqXulsNlmti So instead of returning the error, pass in an error channel and just have it communicate the errors rather than returning unless the context is canceled.  Note, with this example if the error channel is not being consumed (as in reportErrors) f2 will block indefinitely after its first error.